# UserAgent will be deprecated - Impacts on GXT

Tags: gwt, user-agent, gxt, client-hints

Last week, we received information that the user-agent has its days counted.

Google announced that it will get rid of the User-Agent String in Chrome and Mozilla/Microsoft support the idea.
I'm wondering what will be the impact on that for GXT specific code, and how will we be able to build, and later, how the loading script may choose which permutation to use.
Any thoughts on that?

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!msg/blink-dev/-2JIRNMWJ7s/yHe4tQNLCgAJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it seems that Chrome team plans to "freeze" UA string, while at the same time they would be providing an alternative mechanism to getting UA information using UA Client Hints. GWT could still operate with "frozen" UA string, or could be extended to use new API to get exact information on supported features by particular client browser.

Comment: Well, that is Chrome team's plans. I hope others (Mozilla) will do the same, but I am not sure. If they decide not to freeze and simply remove it, then a new version of gwt will be required. But my concern is also about gxt...

Comment: It's not possible to remove UA as many more things will break "break the internet anyone", not just GWT/GXT. So have no fear :)